# Automatic extract zipped files with passwords in the file name

Tags: automation

I analyse data from being sent multiple ZIP files.
They are always in this format:

```
service_SC30COM_####_20191130_1834.zip
```

#### is a random number generated by the computer.
Password is SC30COM_####, which is always part of the file name.

Any suggestions on an automation to unzip in bulk?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Some more info is required as OS, unzip software...

Comment: I am just using windows 10 - open to suggestions on how to achieve this function

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it on the command prompt without any application.
You can check [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c471780f-6c08-4c0b-9478-e51d196b6a78/powershell-to-unzip-file-having-passowrd?forum=winserverpowershell)

If your remove the password, the code you need, as explain in that microsoft article should be:

```
$shell=new-object -com shell.application

$CurrentLocation=get-location

$CurrentPath=$CurrentLocation.path

$Location=$shell.namespace($CurrentPath)

$ZipFiles = get-childitem *.zip

$ZipFiles.count | out-default

foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles)

{

$ZipFile.fullname | out-default

$ZipFolder = $shell.namespace($ZipFile.fullname)

$Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items())

}
```

If you install any application that can run on command prompt, you can extract with password. As example, for a individual file, the maximum you will get on Windows 10 is:

> `PowerShell Expand-Archive -Path "C:\Users\Tuffy\Desktop\PowerShell
>   Expand-Archive -Path "C:\Users\Whatever\Desktop\service_SC30COM_####_20191130_1834.zip"
>   -DestinationPath "C:\Users\Whatever\Desktop"p" -DestinationPath "C:\Whatever\Tuffy\Desktop"`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following code as a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in *.zip
do
    echo "Unzipping $FILE ..."
    PASSWORD=$(echo  $FILE | grep -o -P '(?<=service_)[A-Za-z0-9]*_[0-9]*(?=_)')
    unzip -P $PASSWORD $FILE
done
```

1. Copy the code
2. Paste it into FILENAME.sh
3. Make it executable (chmod +x FILENAME.sh)
4. Put it besides the zip files
5. Run it (./FILENAME.sh)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 

Is this possible as a .BAT file? I have made a few simple Bat files in the past, but never a Bash script - is that linux only?

Comment: Sure something similar should be possible within a .BAT file. A simple solution would be to install [GitBash](https://git-scm.com/) and give the .sh file a shot.